# Payment for articles in journals

Tags: publications, journals, career-path

The mainstream academic publishing model assumes that authors are somehow paid by third parties (typically universities or industry) for the time spent on research. With increasing casualisation of the academic workforce (particularly in the humanities) this is arguably less appropriate than it once was, and many authors are no longer paid for the time spent on research. Amongst other things, this has strong negative consequences for diversity, as it biases the system towards those who can afford to work 'for free'.

An alternative model could involve authors being paid directly by journals for their submissions (as is common for, say, freelance journalists). Has this ever been tried in academia? Is it a realistic possibility?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. You may want to check out our [help]; we are strictly a Q&A site, not a discussion board. That said: I think there may be an answerable question here: please consider [editing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/156244/edit) your post to focus on "Do journals ever pay contributors?" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any journals in my field (physical sciences) that would pay cash to authors for research papers. There are some obvious edge-cases:

- Some major journals such as Science/Nature contain a certain amount of non-research content, e.g. 'science news' and commentary on policy matters. I presume that the authors of this material get paid fairly directly for their efforts to produce it. However, one might argue these individuals are acting as 'journalists' rather than 'academics' when they do so.
- Some journals carry book reviews. I think it is fairly common that the author of the review gets to keep their review copy of the book. For a major textbook, this may have non-negligible financial value.
- Some grants/awards, especially those from professional societies, may come with some obligation to contribute a report to one of the society's journals. However, the award is not (in any case that I know) expressly claimed to be payment for the journal contribution.

Researchers in certain areas have opportunities to profit from private consultancy arrangements with industry/commercial enterprises. In some cases, this may entail conducting and publishing studies with a particular focus (typically, to prove that the company's products are safe/effective/better than the competition). Anecdotally, this is particularly prevalent in medical fields. Of course, there are many potential ethical issues here.

Otherwise, the general assumption in the physical sciences is that authors do so in the course of their employment at a university/research institute/company, or as students working towards a degree (for which they may receive some scholarship/grant). Of course, there is a big difference with the humanities here, due to the relative abundance of research funding for the sciences.

That said, it is interesting to note that publications are (largely) required only to *get* or *improve* a job, rather than to keep it. An academic who habitually failed to show up to teach their assigned classes would likely find themselves facing disciplinary action. However, an academic who fails to publish rarely sees any personal consequences until the next time their employment falls to be reviewed  (either as a tenure/promotion/contract renewal case, or because they've applied for a new job).

I presume the premise of your question is that many academics have teaching-only contracts, and therefore any research they do is 'in their own time'. The issue here, as I see it, is that people who want one career path (academic research) are being encouraged to take a different one (academic teaching) and view it as a 'stepping stone' to research. This is a huge problem, but I'm not sure that either the blame or the solution lies with the publishing process.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a portion of the science/nature commentaries are written by academics, and are not paid.

Comment: "an academic who fails to publish rarely sees any personal consequences until the next time their employment falls to be reviewed"  Until there are layoffs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your comment, "Of course, there is a big difference with the humanities here..." gets to the heart of what I'm asking. I'm in the humanities and there are no outside consultancy opportunities for $$. Independent academics or adjuncts have no obligation to publish, yet might WANT to add to academic discourse. Shouldn't they be paid for their labor particularly when the journal is university-backed, i.e. has a budget and is sold to libraries or individuals through subscription? What ideas and voices are lost because some cannot literally afford to work for free?

Comment: @Isabelle To play devil's advocate: My dream was to be a soccer star, but I didn't manage to get signed by any major clubs. I still enjoy playing, so I turn up on a Sunday and play for my village team. Should I get paid? After all, I'm doing the same work as Ronaldo, kicking a ball around.

Comment: @avid Totally on point. I have used the analogy that academic writing is relegated to an expensive hobby for those not funded (or even costs money if we're paying for childcare or turning down paid work to do it). I've said the same about conferences — if I have 1K of disposable income I can drop it on flight, hotel, meals, fees or go on a "real" vacation. Yet the trouble with the "but it's a choice" argument is that academia suffers when those for whom working for free is NOT a possibility and they are systemically excluded from their fields. "Choice," in this case, is an illusion.

Answer (score 0):

> Academics are no longer tenure-track, nor tenured

Then they get paid for teaching, not for research.  But even so they do still get fringe benefits like library access.

Some few academics make a living from royalties if their textbook happens to be widely used in large-enrollment undergraduate courses.

Comment: I agree about textbooks, (though think it's still rare), but that's a commercial contract.  I'm asking about university-backed journals where there is a budget, and even profit being made through subscription sales, yet the contributors receive zero actual payment for their labor.  Agreed, those adjuncting get some benefits through their jobs, and publishing is considered optional, but if they do contribute a stellar article to a selective journal, why should this be treated as, essentially, volunteer work if there is a university budget and others editing the journal are being paid?